# Bash prompt not recognizing Unicode escapes

Tags: bash, quoting, prompt

I'm trying to customize my Bash prompt with Unicode characters and I'm having a bit of trouble. If I try to include a Unicode character like this:

```
$ echo ☢ | hexdump -C
00000000  e2 98 a2 0a                                       |....|
00000004

$ PS1="\xe2\x98\xa2\x0a"
```

I see my prompt appears like this:

```
\xe2\x98\xa2\x0a
```

...rather than showing the ☢ character. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not valid `bash` escape syntax for simple double quotes.  Try instead

```
PS1=$'\xe2\x98\xa2 '
```

This uses the special [`$'...'` quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) that `bash` has and which does support ANSI C escapes.  Note that the `0a` is just linefeed (newline character) and I doubt you want that, so I took the liberty of replacing it with a space above.

Of course, instead of going through the entire rigamarole of finding the UTF-8 encoding, and then typing out the escapes, you could just use the raw character itself (`PS1='☢ '`) and it would still work.

Comment: \*facepalm\* why didn't I think of just trying the character!?

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of bash, you can also use the Unicode value:

```
PS1=$'\u2622 '
```

That way, it will get expanded/displayed properly (or at least not as bad) even if the local charset/encoding is not utf-8 (or it will cause bash to crash or output rubbish as I think I've uncovered a bug there).

Comment: Very nice. I was wondering if/why this feature wasn't present. Somehow, I feel better about including `\u2622` than a raw Unicode character `☢`.